# Change JFrame(without layout) to JPanel

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, layout-manager, null-layout-manager

I have to change my program's GUI implemented in Swing. Now I have many charts in seperate windows and I want to change it so they all display in only one. The constraction of the orginal version was that 
JFrame had a JPanel field. JFrame had no set layout.

```
private void initComponents() {// GEN-BEGIN:initComponents

        getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        setTitle("Wykres");
        addComponentListener(new java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter() {
            public void componentResized(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent evt) {
                resizedWindow(evt);
            }
        });
        addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
                exitForm(evt);
            }
        });

        java.awt.Dimension screenSize = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        setBounds((screenSize.width - MIN_WIDTH) / 2, (screenSize.height - MIN_HEIGHT) / 2, MIN_WIDTH, MIN_HEIGHT);
    }
```

JPanel was declared as follows:

```
BorderLayout borderLayout = new BorderLayout();
            borderLayout.setHgap(0);
            borderLayout.setVgap(0);
            drawPanel = new JDrawPanel();
            drawPanel.setLayout(borderLayout);
            drawPanel.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.UNKNOWN);
setContentPane(drawPanel);
```

If I remove inheritance by JFrame and add inheritance by JPanel, the method paintComponent is not called. I think the reason is bad layout settings. However program calculates the distances from the edges, and I don't want to change it. How can I easily edit this program?

I also generated new GUI in NETBEANS

```
public class ViewPanel extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public ViewPanel() {
       // initComponents();
    }
    public ViewPanel(JPanel histo, JPanel dystrybu, JPanel time){
        initComponents(histo, dystrybu, time);
    }
    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents(JPanel histo, JPanel dystrybu, JPanel time) {

        MainTabs = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
        jHistoTab = histo;
        jDystybuTab = dystrybu;
        jTimeTab = time;



        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("zaleznosc czasowa");

        MainTabs.setToolTipText("");
        MainTabs.addTab("histogram", jHistoTab);
        MainTabs.addTab("dystrybuanta", jDystybuTab);
        MainTabs.addTab("zalenosc czasowa", jTimeTab);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(MainTabs, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 712, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(MainTabs, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 363, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        MainTabs.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleName("");


        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ViewPanel.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ViewPanel.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ViewPanel.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ViewPanel.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new ViewPanel().setVisible(true);
                AppSMO.main(null);
            }
        });
    }
    public void setHistoTab(JPanel panel){
        jHistoTab=panel;
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JTabbedPane MainTabs;
    private JPanel jDystybuTab;
    private JPanel jHistoTab;
    private JPanel jTimeTab;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Answer (score 0):

Set a BorderLayout to the contentpane. Add your panel to the contentPane. 
That will give it center constraint so it will adapt to the size of the window.
In the panel you are then free to add any components you need. I recommend that you don't use null layout anywhere. 
Avoid absolute positioning.

Comment: *"I recommend that you don't use null layout anywhere."* 3rd sentence is too late for that advice. It should be 1st sentence in its own paragraph.